# Putting UILabel in center of Collection View?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want a UILabel to appear in the center of my Collection View with a background color. However, when I drag one onto the view in my Storyboard and set its background color it seems to take up the whole view. Instead I want it to just take up a small rectangular section that just surrounds its text within. Here's what I have and what I want it to look like:

**Current:**

[image: storyboard]

**Goal:**

[image: want]

Is there any way to set the labels height and width manually? I want it to continue its current behavior of appearing over the cells that get generated in the collection view, but to only take up a limited amount of space instead of taking up the whole view.

Comment: set frame of your lable that you want and at last make label.layer.makstobound = true

Comment: Are you sure that you want the label to be as a subview of the collection?

Comment: @AhmadF I just want it to always appear in the middle of the view, with an outlet that I can change it's text and opacity

Comment: drag an uiview on outside your viewcontroller and use it as subview in code

Comment: Hold down command when you drag the label onto the collection view, it will prevent it from adding it as a subview of the collection view. Your collection view is giving the label it's frame.

Comment: @MarksCode even if the collectionView has many cell, right?

Comment: @AhmadF, yes, for it to be absolutely positioned in the center

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT:

Thanks to @robmayoff for commenting that this solution is not possible in case of *collection view controller*.

This Answer is applicable only if you have a *regular view controller* **but not** a *collection view controller*.

The reason why I'm didn't delete it because -hopefully- it might be useful for some of other viewers.

---

I suggest to:

- Let the label behind the collectionView:

From here (document outline):

[image]

Drag the label to be on top of the collectionView (not as a subview). Make sure that both of the components at the same hierarchy, but the label is behind the collectionView. Once you've done this,

- Double click on the label (also from the document outline):

Now you are able to move it to the center of the view (by using the arrows on the keyboard for example), make sure to let it be at the center of the screen.

- Add the appropriate constraints to let the label to be always in the center of screen.
- Make the background of collectionView transperent (clear color).

That's it!

I hope this helps.

Comment: You cannot put the label on top of the collection view inside a Collection View Controller scene. The collection view is always the root view in a Collection View Controller scene. All other views in the scene must be descendants of the collection view. They cannot be siblings of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Please follow the below steps:**

- Create an extension of CollectionView
- Add the Below function in it.

  ```
    extension UICollectionView {
    func setMessage(_ message: String) {
        let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        messageLabel.text = message
        messageLabel.textColor = .black
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()

        self.backgroundView = messageLabel
    } 
    func removeMessage() {
        self.backgroundView = nil
    }
    }
  ```
- If you want to remove that message then just use the above `removeMessage()` function.

**Usages**

- To set message:

  `self.collcetionview.setMessage("message")`
- To remove the message:

  `self.collcetionview.removeEmptyMessage()`

Answer (score 1):

- Drag a UIView and place it in the collection view to cover it completely.
- Drag a UILabel and give its height and width constraint in storyboard and also set constraint for centre in horizontally and vertically.
- You also need to set the height and width of collection view in code as shown below

  ```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cellHeight)
  }
  ```